# Grandchildren component selection or Reusing code in components

Tags: angular

I have an angular 6 site that displays financial reports for end users.  each "report" is made up of a number of "widgets." I end up repeating a lot of code for each widget.  It seems like i should be able to reduce the amount of code i am typing.

I have searched for examples, but keep getting results for how to pass variables between components rather than what I am trying to do.

```
what I have:      
      <div class="card flex-fill w-100">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h5 class="card-title mb-0">{{section3title}}</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body py-3">   
            <app-assetbyentity
              [jsondata] = 'section3data'>
            </app-assetbyentity>              
        </div>
    </div>

what I would like to achieve:   
    <widget
        [title] = 'section3tile'>
    <app-assetbyentity
        [jsondata] = 'section3data'>
    </app-assetbyentity>      
    </widget>
```

I end up including the

```
<div class="card flex-fill w-100">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h5 class="card-title mb-0">{{section3title}}</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body py-3">
```

code 40 times throughout the site. I have to go back and change a lot of code whenever I made a change to the overall look of each report.  I think I want to determine the grandchild component from the parent, but can't find the right google terms to find relevant examples. if anyone will point me in the right direction, i would appreciate it.